# Is it possible to wait for fs.watch to detect all files when dropping them to a dir?

Tags: node.js, fs, watch

I have a directory where I want to watch files. I drop one or more files at a time every now and then.
Whenever I drop multiple files I want to pass a callback to `fs.watch` when all files are read because I want to do an action in bulk.

Is this possible? How?
Can I still keep the normal callback for logging filenames to console?

I was thinking that maybe I could use `Promise.all`?

Here is my code so far:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const file = "towatch/";
console.log(`Watching for file changes on ${file}`);

fs.watch(file, (eventType, changedFile) => {
  console.log(`File Changed ${changedFile}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want there to be a time window to wait to see if multiple files are dropped into the folder.

You might implement this by having changed files be pushed onto a queue instead of being processed directly. You could then setTimeout with a callback to process the files based on what you want the time window to be. Everytime a new file is added clear and restart the callback and if you dont receive any new files the processing callback will execute.